# How to get one drive files that are shared by you using graph api?

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, spfx

We have an graph api to get one drive files that are "shared to you". But just wanted to understand if there is any possible way that get one drive files that are "shared by you".

Approach that we are following now:

- Get all the drive files and folders from the root folder and target
  for shared property
- But the cons of it is it should recursively
  search for each folder and have to call each folder in one drive
  with graph api to check for shared property.

Answer (score 0):

So far, MS Graph does not support listing files shared from a drive. The operation you are doing also seems very expensive especially when you have a nested hierarchy of files. Possible options have the same con of recursive search.

You can create a feature request for it on the [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so that it may be implemented in the future.